# Error (Hung process?) when using COPY INTO with ANSI file

Tags: python, monetdb

I'm trying to load a set of public flat files (using `COPY INTO` from Python) - that apparently are saved in `ANSI` format.  Some of the files load with no issue, but there is at least one case where the `COPY INTO` statement hangs (no error is returned, & nothing is logged, as far as I can tell).  I isolated the error to a particular row with a non-standard character e.g., the `¢` character in the 2nd row -

```
O}10}49771}2020}02}202002}4977110}141077}71052900}R }}N}0}0}0}0}0}0}0}0}0}0}0}0}0}0}0}0}08}CWI STATE A}CENTENNIAL RESOURCE PROD, LLC}PHANTOM (WOLFCAMP)


O}10}50367}2020}01}202001}5036710}027348}73933500}R }}N}0}0}0}0}0}0}0}0}0}0}0}0}0}0}0}0}08}A¢C 34-197}APC WATER HOLDINGS 1, LLC}QUITO, WEST (DELAWARE)
```

Re-saving these rows into a file with UTF-8 encoding solves the issue, but I thought I'd pass this along in case someone wants to take a look at the back-end to handle these types of characters and/or return some kind of error.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you save into a file?

If it is possible, just play with strings internally from Python with:

```
resultstr= bytestr.encode("utf-8")
```

Comment: Hello, I am trying to load a source file - it is 9 GB in size (approximately 70 million rows).  The COPY INTO statement is expecting a file - hence the need to adjust the encoding of the file.